# Same sign of two integers

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Please have a look at my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void checksign(int, int);
bool samesign(int, int);

int main() {
    printf("Check same sign\n\n");

    int a = 27952, b = -68643, c = 0;

    checksign(a, a);
    checksign(a, b);
    checksign(a, c);
    checksign(b, b);
    checksign(b, c);
    checksign(c, c);

    return 0;
}

void checksign(int a, int b) {
    printf("%d and %d have ", a, b);
    if (!samesign(a, b)) {
        printf("not ");
    }
    printf("the same sign.\n");
}

bool samesign(int a, int b) {
    return (a | 0) == (b | 0);
}
```

I read the related topics here, which all showed reasonable solutions.
I really can't understand why/how my samesign function works (at least for me, on a 64-bit Linux, compiled with GCC 7.3.0).
Any help or insight is appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't work. Your test suite is incomplete. Try comparing **different** positive numbers.

Comment: `return a >> (sizeof a * CHAR_BIT - 1) == b >> (sizeof b * CHAR_BIT - 1);` may be another option.

Comment: Better `bool samesign(unsigned a, unsigned b)` and I'd just make the return `int`.

Comment: Seeing `-0 == +0`: Do you consider `0` as positive or negative?

Comment: Maybe it was supposed to read (a < 0) == (b < 0)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original code is completely wrong, as `a | 0 == a` for all `a`, and so `(a|0) == (b|0)` is equivalent to `a == b`.

For *signed* `a, b`, return false if they have opposing signs. Please note that 0 is considered to have a positive sign, even though `-0 == 0`. A naive implentation is provided below.

```
bool samesign(int a, int b) {
    if ((a < 0) && (b >= 0))
        return false;
    if ((a >= 0) && (b < 0))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

However... **There is a more clever and efficient solution using just *one* line, using bit manipulation and just thinking about the sign bit (based on two's complement numbers):**

```
bool samesign(int a, int b) {
    /* Sign bit of XOR is 1 if only one of a or b is negative. */
    /* That means, signed a XOR b is negative if they have opposing signs. */
    return (signed int)(a ^ b) >= 0;
}
```

Your expected results should be:

```
27952 and 27952 have the same sign.
27952 and -68643 have not the same sign.
27952 and 0 have the same sign.
-68643 and -68643 have the same sign.
-68643 and 0 have the same sign. 
0 and 0 have the same sign.
```

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer. I got it finally :-) Interesting to see, how to make and overlook such a trivial thing.